# Displaying only 1 column in last row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've checked the queries in phpMyAdmin a lot of times and is dead sure they are absolutely correct. Also, if I manually write the loop 3 times, setting 2,3,4 instead of incrementing counter it still displays ONLY one column in last row. First two rows result is accurate.

`foreach($row as $rec)` is basically running 17 times from another query which is printing table headers.

```
$by_type1 = array("First","Second+","Final"); 
$counter = 2; //this counter represents type of interview (2-First, 3-Second+, 4-Final)

foreach ($by_type1 as $type1) 
{    
    $table_row = '<tr><td class="rborder">'.$type1.'</td>';

    foreach ($row as $rec)
    {
        $id=$rec['id'];
        $qry2 = "SELECT 
            CONCAT( r.fname, ' ', r.lname ) AS rname, 
            ch.status_id as Type, 
            count(ch.status_id) as number

            FROM candidateJoborderHistory ch 

            LEFT JOIN candidates_info c ON ch.candidate_id = c.candidate_id 
            LEFT JOIN recruiters r ON c.recruiter_id=r.recruiter_id 
            LEFT JOIN interviewtypes i ON ch.interview_id = i.interview_id 

            WHERE c.recruiter_id = $id AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ch.date_interview) BETWEEN 1401667200 AND     
            1402099200 AND ch.status_id = $counter
            group by ch.status_id";

        global $conn;
        $conn->open();
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare($qry2);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $row2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();

        foreach($row2 as $row_x)
        { 
            $table_row .= '<td>'.$row_x['number'].'</td>';
        }
    }

    $table_row .='</tr>';
    echo $table_row . "\n";
    $counter++;
}
```

What I want is:

```
First   6   6   4   4   11  6   12  3
Second+ 3   1   2   1   3
Final   3   2   1   4   1
```

But what I am getting is:

```
First   6   6   4   4   11  6   12  3
Second+ 3   1   2   1   3
Final   3
```

Comment: Could you please provide a ´var_dump($row2);´ result for ´$counter==4´?

Comment: foreach($row2 as $row_x) runs as many times as there is a match. In my database it comes 8,5,5 matches in 3 loops (First, Second+,Final) respectively. Though it just prints 8,5,1 elements. Hope I was able to give a better picture.

Comment: Sure! I agree and understand your problem, but 8, 5, 5 matches of what? null values won't print a cell... could you please update with ´var_dump´ please? Also, could you paste HTML generated... it will help. :)

Comment: Thanks it gets a little more clear. I did var_dump ($row2) after the end of innermost foreach loop. All values are perfect (results for matches,array(0) { } where there is no match) until the last outermost loop ("Final"). After the first value in that loop which is correct it just says (array(0) { }). Which most probably means it's not able fetch the results from the database. Query in myPhpAdmin works perfectly though. @ZeroWorks.

Comment: @ZeroWorks, I just tried query changing the UNIX TIMESTAMP for a different period. Same Problem. Last loop values are not being fetched. And the new query again works perfectly with myPhpAdmin. Totally clueless. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think that is a MySQL approach, I've made some changes to your code and explained them:

```
$by_type1 = array(2=>"First", 3=>"Second+", 4=>"Final"); 
$counter = 2; //this counter represents type of interview (2-First, 3-Second+, 4-Final)

// Open connection first.
global $conn;
$conn->open();

// Using key => value array gets code simple
foreach ($by_type1 as $counter=>$type1) 
{    
    $table_row = '<tr><td class="rborder">'.$type1.'</td>';

    foreach ($row as $rec)
    {
        $id=$rec['id'];

        $qry2 = "SELECT 
            CONCAT( r.fname, ' ', r.lname ) AS rname, 
            ch.status_id as Type, 
            count(ch.status_id) as number

            FROM candidateJoborderHistory ch 

            LEFT JOIN candidates_info c ON ch.candidate_id = c.candidate_id 
            LEFT JOIN recruiters r ON c.recruiter_id=r.recruiter_id 
            LEFT JOIN interviewtypes i ON ch.interview_id = i.interview_id 

            WHERE c.recruiter_id = $id 
            AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ch.date_interview) 
            BETWEEN 1401667200 AND 1402099200 
            AND ch.status_id = $counter
            GROUP BY ch.status_id"; 

            $res = $conn->prepare($qry2);
            $res->execute();

        // Loop to get data...
         while($row_x = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
            $table_row .= '<td>'.$row_x['number'].'</td>';
        }

    }

    $table_row .='</tr>';
    echo $table_row . "\n";
}
$conn->close();
```

Code isn't tested but if you have any doubt just ask. Hope it helps!

References:

[Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
[Executing Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_assoc() at line "while($row_x=$res->fetch_assoc())"            
:(

Comment: I changed it to "while($row_x = $res->fetchAll())" which gives the right number of cells that is 8,5,5 cells but empty cells. I guess we're close. Can you think of something.

Comment: DONE :D
while($row_x = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)). Thanks for all the help and discussion. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: You're welcome. As a suggestion and for further questions if you upvote the right answer you will give 25 points instead of 15.

Comment: I cant right now. Minimum reputation to VoteUp is 15, I've 10. Just started using Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: This is easy to solve... Now you've 20. :) Don't worry i dont' need it only was a suggestion. Thank you!